# How to use special characters inside code block

Tags: docsify

many characters break the code block, while viewing the same on github looks OK without any error....

example, try to render this :

````
move the new part when needed
```
@echo off
::example of filename Test_1.dat / Test_2.dat etc.
set file="Test_*.dat"
set dest="E:\INPUTDATA\LOAD\"
set src="E:\files_for_load\"
set inprogress="E:\INPUTDATA\INPROGRESS\*.dat"

:hi
if exist %dest%%file% (
    echo file exists, files INPROGRESS now
    dir %inprogress%  /s/b
) ELSE (
    echo file not exists
    for %%a in (%src%%file%) do (
        echo %%a
        move %%a %dest%
        goto hi
    )
goto hend
)

timeout /t 30

goto hi

:hend
echo All the files processed!
pause
```
````

[image]

any solution ?